# MySQL initial statement in ODBC connector (under windows) not taking effect

Tags: mysql, odbc

I'm using MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver under Windows to connect to my database. In the "Initial Statement" field I configured it to run `SET SESSION binlog_format = 'ROW'` when connection starts. It was working all fine, until yesterday, when I needed to restart mysql database server.

Not, all connections are not initiated with this binlog format, and use system default instead. Running `show variables like '%binlog%'` from that server shows 'STATEMENT' instead of 'ROW'.

I tried enabling debug logging in the driver, but it does not show any useful info. Tried restarting mysql server - no luck. Looked in error logs in both Event Viewer, and on mysql server - no indication that anything is wrong.

Anyone has any idea on what might be not right here?

EDIT: checked privileges (as Charles suggested), and user has all privileges on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be resolved by re-installing the driver.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL manual page on changing `binlog_format` on the fly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-setting.html) indicates that the running user *must* have the `SUPER` priv as of 5.1.29.  Can you check the permissions on the user you're connecting with?  I'm willing to bet that your user isn't `SUPER` any longer, though I would really expect MySQL to complain about this.

Comment: User does have SUPER privileges, and access server-wide

Comment: Odd.  Do you have the same problem issuing the commands at the MySQL prompt, instead of via PHP?

Comment: Using MySQL prompt - no problems. PHP from another server - no problems. This specific server is windows, and ODBC is used to connect MySQL with SQL Server, so there is no PHP. The problem shows when running queries through SQL server.

Comment: @Serge, can you rephrase that, please?  It sounds like you said that the problem happens when you ask SQL Server to give commands to MySQL via ODBC, and I'm not sure my mind is willing to accept this possibility.  :)

Comment: @Charles, that is exactly the case ;)

Comment: @Serge, thanks, I learned something new today.  Okay, so, uh... hm.  Do you have another thing on the system that can connect to MySQL *via ODBC* and can issue the same commands?  Because I don't think I have any better ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately - nothing else I can run on the server, as it is a production machine. For now, I patched it up by setting format to MIXED on MySQL side, so that initial statement is not needed... But why it doesn't work, or why it worked before still puzzles me... :(